Need hint how to reduce the gaps between theses bars in PowerBI bar chart
I'm working on a project of data elections for a homework on PowerBI desktop. It's very simple datas, but how do we manage tocut the gap between a bar that is far aways from the other bars?
Suppose we have these two data series :
x-axis = voters section
y-axis = numbers of votes
The y-axis, there's no problem at all. However, the x-axis, I have a problem to display it correctly since I have this list of voters section : 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, ..., 56, 57, 302.
I don't know why there is a 302 out of nowhere, probably due to mapping limits... Well. So, with that said, I have a terrible graph looks like this :
Graph of Votes by voters section
The dash line is the participation rate, it's ok. But you see there's a huge gap just for 1 bar.
Any help/hint I can try to fix it? I how we can truncate the x-axis, but only from the beginning (at 0). Is it possible to do the same between x = 58 and x = 301 ? I tried to display the chart with the Categorical mode, didn't work either ...
Thanks in advance.

is this a good way to display the data? why not set up the vote range? e.g. 1-10 , 11-20

It's because the voters section are all in consecutive order, except for 1.

what's the measure that you used for dot line?

percentage. The dot line is the % of participation (% of voters who voted).

maybe you can try to create a column = if (vote selection>60, ">60", vote selection). This will reduce the gap between the charts.
